# List all liquibase sql types

Tags: java, liquibase

I try to find documentation on the supported types that can be used in change log files.
But cannot find it.
Is there any document, site or something similar where I can find all types-specific issues.
For example clob type is supported in databases with different types. And I have to use something like:

```
<property name="clob.type" value="clob" dbms="oracle,h2,hsqldb"/>
<property name="clob.type" value="longtext" dbms="mysql"/>
<column name="clob1" type="${clob.type}">
    <constraints nullable="true"/>
</column>
```

I hope there is a resource where all liquibase types are described.

Answer (score 320, accepted):

This is a comprehensive list of all liquibase datatypes and how they are converted for different databases:

```
boolean
MySQLDatabase: BIT(1)
SQLiteDatabase: BOOLEAN
H2Database: BOOLEAN
PostgresDatabase: BOOLEAN
UnsupportedDatabase: BOOLEAN
DB2Database: SMALLINT
MSSQLDatabase: [bit]
OracleDatabase: NUMBER(1)
HsqlDatabase: BOOLEAN
FirebirdDatabase: SMALLINT
DerbyDatabase: SMALLINT
InformixDatabase: BOOLEAN
SybaseDatabase: BIT
SybaseASADatabase: BIT

tinyint
MySQLDatabase: TINYINT
SQLiteDatabase: TINYINT
H2Database: TINYINT
PostgresDatabase: SMALLINT
UnsupportedDatabase: TINYINT
DB2Database: SMALLINT
MSSQLDatabase: [tinyint]
OracleDatabase: NUMBER(3)
HsqlDatabase: TINYINT
FirebirdDatabase: SMALLINT
DerbyDatabase: SMALLINT
InformixDatabase: TINYINT
SybaseDatabase: TINYINT
SybaseASADatabase: TINYINT

int
MySQLDatabase: INT
SQLiteDatabase: INTEGER
H2Database: INT
PostgresDatabase: INT
UnsupportedDatabase: INT
DB2Database: INTEGER
MSSQLDatabase: [int]
OracleDatabase: INTEGER
HsqlDatabase: INT
FirebirdDatabase: INT
DerbyDatabase: INTEGER
InformixDatabase: INT
SybaseDatabase: INT
SybaseASADatabase: INT

mediumint
MySQLDatabase: MEDIUMINT
SQLiteDatabase: MEDIUMINT
H2Database: MEDIUMINT
PostgresDatabase: MEDIUMINT
UnsupportedDatabase: MEDIUMINT
DB2Database: MEDIUMINT
MSSQLDatabase: [int]
OracleDatabase: MEDIUMINT
HsqlDatabase: MEDIUMINT
FirebirdDatabase: MEDIUMINT
DerbyDatabase: MEDIUMINT
InformixDatabase: MEDIUMINT
SybaseDatabase: MEDIUMINT
SybaseASADatabase: MEDIUMINT

bigint
MySQLDatabase: BIGINT
SQLiteDatabase: BIGINT
H2Database: BIGINT
PostgresDatabase: BIGINT
UnsupportedDatabase: BIGINT
DB2Database: BIGINT
MSSQLDatabase: [bigint]
OracleDatabase: NUMBER(38, 0)
HsqlDatabase: BIGINT
FirebirdDatabase: BIGINT
DerbyDatabase: BIGINT
InformixDatabase: INT8
SybaseDatabase: BIGINT
SybaseASADatabase: BIGINT

float
MySQLDatabase: FLOAT
SQLiteDatabase: FLOAT
H2Database: FLOAT
PostgresDatabase: FLOAT
UnsupportedDatabase: FLOAT
DB2Database: FLOAT
MSSQLDatabase: [float](53)
OracleDatabase: FLOAT
HsqlDatabase: FLOAT
FirebirdDatabase: FLOAT
DerbyDatabase: FLOAT
InformixDatabase: FLOAT
SybaseDatabase: FLOAT
SybaseASADatabase: FLOAT

double
MySQLDatabase: DOUBLE
SQLiteDatabase: DOUBLE
H2Database: DOUBLE
PostgresDatabase: DOUBLE PRECISION
UnsupportedDatabase: DOUBLE
DB2Database: DOUBLE
MSSQLDatabase: [float](53)
OracleDatabase: FLOAT(24)
HsqlDatabase: DOUBLE
FirebirdDatabase: DOUBLE PRECISION
DerbyDatabase: DOUBLE
InformixDatabase: DOUBLE PRECISION
SybaseDatabase: DOUBLE
SybaseASADatabase: DOUBLE

decimal
MySQLDatabase: DECIMAL
SQLiteDatabase: DECIMAL
H2Database: DECIMAL
PostgresDatabase: DECIMAL
UnsupportedDatabase: DECIMAL
DB2Database: DECIMAL
MSSQLDatabase: [decimal](18, 0)
OracleDatabase: DECIMAL
HsqlDatabase: DECIMAL
FirebirdDatabase: DECIMAL
DerbyDatabase: DECIMAL
InformixDatabase: DECIMAL
SybaseDatabase: DECIMAL
SybaseASADatabase: DECIMAL

number
MySQLDatabase: numeric
SQLiteDatabase: NUMBER
H2Database: NUMBER
PostgresDatabase: numeric
UnsupportedDatabase: NUMBER
DB2Database: numeric
MSSQLDatabase: [numeric](18, 0)
OracleDatabase: NUMBER
HsqlDatabase: numeric
FirebirdDatabase: numeric
DerbyDatabase: numeric
InformixDatabase: numeric
SybaseDatabase: numeric
SybaseASADatabase: numeric

blob
MySQLDatabase: LONGBLOB
SQLiteDatabase: BLOB
H2Database: BLOB
PostgresDatabase: BYTEA
UnsupportedDatabase: BLOB
DB2Database: BLOB
MSSQLDatabase: [varbinary](MAX)
OracleDatabase: BLOB
HsqlDatabase: BLOB
FirebirdDatabase: BLOB
DerbyDatabase: BLOB
InformixDatabase: BLOB
SybaseDatabase: IMAGE
SybaseASADatabase: LONG BINARY

function
MySQLDatabase: FUNCTION
SQLiteDatabase: FUNCTION
H2Database: FUNCTION
PostgresDatabase: FUNCTION
UnsupportedDatabase: FUNCTION
DB2Database: FUNCTION
MSSQLDatabase: [function]
OracleDatabase: FUNCTION
HsqlDatabase: FUNCTION
FirebirdDatabase: FUNCTION
DerbyDatabase: FUNCTION
InformixDatabase: FUNCTION
SybaseDatabase: FUNCTION
SybaseASADatabase: FUNCTION

UNKNOWN
MySQLDatabase: UNKNOWN
SQLiteDatabase: UNKNOWN
H2Database: UNKNOWN
PostgresDatabase: UNKNOWN
UnsupportedDatabase: UNKNOWN
DB2Database: UNKNOWN
MSSQLDatabase: [UNKNOWN]
OracleDatabase: UNKNOWN
HsqlDatabase: UNKNOWN
FirebirdDatabase: UNKNOWN
DerbyDatabase: UNKNOWN
InformixDatabase: UNKNOWN
SybaseDatabase: UNKNOWN
SybaseASADatabase: UNKNOWN

datetime
MySQLDatabase: datetime
SQLiteDatabase: TEXT
H2Database: TIMESTAMP
PostgresDatabase: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
UnsupportedDatabase: datetime
DB2Database: TIMESTAMP
MSSQLDatabase: [datetime]
OracleDatabase: TIMESTAMP
HsqlDatabase: TIMESTAMP
FirebirdDatabase: TIMESTAMP
DerbyDatabase: TIMESTAMP
InformixDatabase: DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(5)
SybaseDatabase: datetime
SybaseASADatabase: datetime

time
MySQLDatabase: time
SQLiteDatabase: time
H2Database: time
PostgresDatabase: TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE
UnsupportedDatabase: time
DB2Database: time
MSSQLDatabase: [time](7)
OracleDatabase: DATE
HsqlDatabase: time
FirebirdDatabase: time
DerbyDatabase: time
InformixDatabase: INTERVAL HOUR TO FRACTION(5)
SybaseDatabase: time
SybaseASADatabase: time

timestamp
MySQLDatabase: timestamp
SQLiteDatabase: TEXT
H2Database: TIMESTAMP
PostgresDatabase: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
UnsupportedDatabase: timestamp
DB2Database: timestamp
MSSQLDatabase: [datetime]
OracleDatabase: TIMESTAMP
HsqlDatabase: TIMESTAMP
FirebirdDatabase: TIMESTAMP
DerbyDatabase: TIMESTAMP
InformixDatabase: DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(5)
SybaseDatabase: datetime
SybaseASADatabase: timestamp

date
MySQLDatabase: date
SQLiteDatabase: date
H2Database: date
PostgresDatabase: date
UnsupportedDatabase: date
DB2Database: date
MSSQLDatabase: [date]
OracleDatabase: date
HsqlDatabase: date
FirebirdDatabase: date
DerbyDatabase: date
InformixDatabase: date
SybaseDatabase: date
SybaseASADatabase: date

char
MySQLDatabase: CHAR
SQLiteDatabase: CHAR
H2Database: CHAR
PostgresDatabase: CHAR
UnsupportedDatabase: CHAR
DB2Database: CHAR
MSSQLDatabase: [char](1)
OracleDatabase: CHAR
HsqlDatabase: CHAR
FirebirdDatabase: CHAR
DerbyDatabase: CHAR
InformixDatabase: CHAR
SybaseDatabase: CHAR
SybaseASADatabase: CHAR

varchar
MySQLDatabase: VARCHAR
SQLiteDatabase: VARCHAR
H2Database: VARCHAR
PostgresDatabase: VARCHAR
UnsupportedDatabase: VARCHAR
DB2Database: VARCHAR
MSSQLDatabase: [varchar](1)
OracleDatabase: VARCHAR2
HsqlDatabase: VARCHAR
FirebirdDatabase: VARCHAR
DerbyDatabase: VARCHAR
InformixDatabase: VARCHAR
SybaseDatabase: VARCHAR
SybaseASADatabase: VARCHAR

nchar
MySQLDatabase: NCHAR
SQLiteDatabase: NCHAR
H2Database: NCHAR
PostgresDatabase: NCHAR
UnsupportedDatabase: NCHAR
DB2Database: NCHAR
MSSQLDatabase: [nchar](1)
OracleDatabase: NCHAR
HsqlDatabase: CHAR
FirebirdDatabase: NCHAR
DerbyDatabase: NCHAR
InformixDatabase: NCHAR
SybaseDatabase: NCHAR
SybaseASADatabase: NCHAR

nvarchar
MySQLDatabase: NVARCHAR
SQLiteDatabase: NVARCHAR
H2Database: NVARCHAR
PostgresDatabase: VARCHAR
UnsupportedDatabase: NVARCHAR
DB2Database: NVARCHAR
MSSQLDatabase: [nvarchar](1)
OracleDatabase: NVARCHAR2
HsqlDatabase: VARCHAR
FirebirdDatabase: NVARCHAR
DerbyDatabase: VARCHAR
InformixDatabase: NVARCHAR
SybaseDatabase: NVARCHAR
SybaseASADatabase: NVARCHAR

clob
MySQLDatabase: LONGTEXT
SQLiteDatabase: TEXT
H2Database: CLOB
PostgresDatabase: TEXT
UnsupportedDatabase: CLOB
DB2Database: CLOB
MSSQLDatabase: [varchar](MAX)
OracleDatabase: CLOB
HsqlDatabase: CLOB
FirebirdDatabase: BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT
DerbyDatabase: CLOB
InformixDatabase: CLOB
SybaseDatabase: TEXT
SybaseASADatabase: LONG VARCHAR

currency
MySQLDatabase: DECIMAL
SQLiteDatabase: REAL
H2Database: DECIMAL
PostgresDatabase: DECIMAL
UnsupportedDatabase: DECIMAL
DB2Database: DECIMAL(19, 4)
MSSQLDatabase: [money]
OracleDatabase: NUMBER(15, 2)
HsqlDatabase: DECIMAL
FirebirdDatabase: DECIMAL(18, 4)
DerbyDatabase: DECIMAL
InformixDatabase: MONEY
SybaseDatabase: MONEY
SybaseASADatabase: MONEY

uuid
MySQLDatabase: char(36)
SQLiteDatabase: TEXT
H2Database: UUID
PostgresDatabase: UUID
UnsupportedDatabase: char(36)
DB2Database: char(36)
MSSQLDatabase: [uniqueidentifier]
OracleDatabase: RAW(16)
HsqlDatabase: char(36)
FirebirdDatabase: char(36)
DerbyDatabase: char(36)
InformixDatabase: char(36)
SybaseDatabase: UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SybaseASADatabase: UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
```

For reference, this is the groovy script I've used to generate this output:

```
@Grab('org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.5.1')

import liquibase.database.core.*
import liquibase.datatype.core.*

def datatypes = [BooleanType,TinyIntType,IntType,MediumIntType,BigIntType,FloatType,DoubleType,DecimalType,NumberType,BlobType,DatabaseFunctionType,UnknownType,DateTimeType,TimeType,TimestampType,DateType,CharType,VarcharType,NCharType,NVarcharType,ClobType,CurrencyType,UUIDType]
def databases = [MySQLDatabase, SQLiteDatabase, H2Database, PostgresDatabase, UnsupportedDatabase, DB2Database, MSSQLDatabase, OracleDatabase, HsqlDatabase, FirebirdDatabase, DerbyDatabase, InformixDatabase, SybaseDatabase, SybaseASADatabase]
datatypes.each {
    def datatype = it.newInstance()
    datatype.finishInitialization("")
    println datatype.name
    databases.each { println "$it.simpleName: ${datatype.toDatabaseDataType(it.newInstance())}"}
    println ''
}
```

Comment: Script to generate list was very helpful!

Comment: Be careful! In PostgreSQL, **float** gives **double precision** (aka **float8**)

Comment: And worse: Column data type "real" incorrectly translated to "double precision" for PostgreSQL, see https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2807

Comment: PostgreSQL **blob** translates to **oid** since 3.5.2 (http://www.liquibase.org/2016/09/liquibase-3-5-2-released.html)

Comment: Actually "float" ist mapped to DOUBLE(17) in H2!

Comment: Friendly reminder when reading the list: for Postgres numeric == decimal

Comment: In version 2.0.x, boolean is transformed into tinyint instead of bit for Mysql.

Comment: I have a column defined as Text on a PostGre Create SQL. I did not define it as a CLOB. Will I still be able to migrate to lets say a DB which has clob as type later?

Comment: What about the postgreSQL jsonb data type?

Answer (score 49):

I've found the `liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.AbstractTypeConverter` class.
It lists all types that can be used:

```
protected DataType getDataType(String columnTypeString, Boolean autoIncrement, String dataTypeName, String precision, String additionalInformation) {
    // Translate type to database-specific type, if possible
    DataType returnTypeName = null;
    if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("BIGINT")) {
        returnTypeName = getBigIntType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("NUMBER") || dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("NUMERIC")) {
        returnTypeName = getNumberType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("BLOB")) {
        returnTypeName = getBlobType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("BOOLEAN")) {
        returnTypeName = getBooleanType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("CHAR")) {
        returnTypeName = getCharType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("CLOB")) {
        returnTypeName = getClobType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("CURRENCY")) {
        returnTypeName = getCurrencyType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("DATE") || dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase(getDateType().getDataTypeName())) {
        returnTypeName = getDateType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("DATETIME") || dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase(getDateTimeType().getDataTypeName())) {
        returnTypeName = getDateTimeType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("DOUBLE")) {
        returnTypeName = getDoubleType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("FLOAT")) {
        returnTypeName = getFloatType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("INT")) {
        returnTypeName = getIntType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("INTEGER")) {
        returnTypeName = getIntType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("LONGBLOB")) {
        returnTypeName = getLongBlobType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("LONGVARBINARY")) {
        returnTypeName = getBlobType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("LONGVARCHAR")) {
        returnTypeName = getClobType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("SMALLINT")) {
        returnTypeName = getSmallIntType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("TEXT")) {
        returnTypeName = getClobType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("TIME") || dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase(getTimeType().getDataTypeName())) {
        returnTypeName = getTimeType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.toUpperCase().contains("TIMESTAMP")) {
        returnTypeName = getDateTimeType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("TINYINT")) {
        returnTypeName = getTinyIntType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("UUID")) {
        returnTypeName = getUUIDType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("VARCHAR")) {
        returnTypeName = getVarcharType();
    } else if (dataTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("NVARCHAR")) {
        returnTypeName = getNVarcharType();
    } else {
        return new CustomType(columnTypeString,0,2);
    }
```

Comment: things are now a littme more complicated - https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/core/NumberType.java now shows how "Number" is converted , and that @DataTypeInfo(name="number", aliases = {"numeric", "java.sql.Types.NUMERIC"}, ....  overall everything is a generic LiquibaseDataType, with a .toDatabaseDataType() function, and a type provided list of aliases.

Comment: seeing there is no json type , what do we do in that case , as postgress supports the type json ?

Answer (score 8):

Well, since liquibase is open source there's always the [source code](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/tree/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/core) which you could check.

Some of the data type classes seem to have a method `toDatabaseDataType()` which should give you information about what type works (is used) on a specific data base.

Comment: See the link above for Liquibase 3.* types-- listed in the directory listing by name. (Notably, DECIMAL is present).

Answer (score 0):

For checking type conversions in version 3, you can go to their github and check into the different liquibase types and check the method toDatabaseDataType.
For example, for Boolean, you can check here:

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/core/BooleanType.java

For version 2.0.x, the conversion seems to be into database specific classes. For example, for Mysql:

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/2_0_x/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/database/typeconversion/core/MySQLTypeConverter.java