# Liquibase Data Type Mapping documentation

Tags: database, grails, types, liquibase

Sorry, this question seems stupid, but I tried 1 hour searching and didn't find anything.
So I'm using liquibase for multiple databases(e.g. MSSQL, Oracle and MySQL), when I say:

```
addColumn(tableName: "ABC_TEST") {
  column(name: "IS_ACTIVE", type: "boolean")
}
```

How do I know if the type "boolean" will be converted to proper types for each database?
And is there any documentation I can find for the data type mapping? If I want to add one more column which is foreign key, which type should I use?

Comment: When you say multiple database, Grails (2.0 and above) has built in capability for [multiple datasources](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources), have you tried that?

Comment: @dmahapatro What you mentioned is data source config, that's not a problem. My problem is mostly about migration scripts. And i want one migration script to work for multiple databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16890723/332248) (and answers) to see the available types that liquibase offers.

In my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16894478/332248) to that question there is a link to the relevant liquibase classes that do the translation to the db specific types.

When you created the table that has the primary key with a "liquibase type" then liquibase will have translated this to the db specific type. 
Then your foreign key should just use the same type and liquibase will translate this likewise.

E.g. check out the class [`BigIntType`](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/core/BigIntType.java).
With liquibase you would just use the "liquibase type": `BIGINT`. 
On Oracle DBs it will translate to `("NUMBER", 38,0)`.
On MSSQL it will translate to `("BIGINT")`.

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase has a concept of database dialects, much like Hibernate's. It uses these to know how to generate the correct DDL statements to add/change/delete columns, foreign keys, etc. When it connects to the database it uses the JDBC metadata to determine which database type you're using, and uses that to determine the correct dialect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got this general idea. My problem is that, if now I want to add a new column which is a foreign key, which type should I use? In our project, I saw people used 'bigint' for mssql or 'number' for oracle. Is there any general type, say 'id', in liquibase, so that liquibase will convert it to specific dialects for each database, and therefore I just put type as 'id' and don't need to worry about the specific types for each database ?