# How can I specify MySQL data type for String in JDL-Studio

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, liquibase

In my JDL file I have a file with the following contents

```
entity Application {
...
text String,
...
```

}

When the XML file is generated for liquibase the MySQL data type is set to `varchar(255)` by default, I want to have `text` or `mediumtext` as the type instead.

```
 <column name="text" type="text">
            <constraints nullable="true" />
  </column>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JDL's TextBlob type for longer strings.  That uses the `clob` Liquibase type which is mapped to `longtext` or `text` [depending on the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890723/list-all-liquibase-sql-types).

```
entity Application {
    text TextBlob
}
```

https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#blobdeclaration