# Logical AND on boolean columns in SQL

Tags: sql

How can we logically AND-connect two boolean columns in SQL *in the select clause*?

Pseudo-SQL of what I have in mind:

```
select boolean_col_A AND boolean_col_B as joint_bool from foo where id = 42
```

Note that I am not limiting the number of records through a boolean predicate but rather create a "synthetic" i.e. surrogate column in the result set.

I feel there must be a simple way to achieve this but I'm not seeing it. It should work for Oracle, Postgres and H2.

Comment: Doesnt your syntax work? If not, try using `if(a and b, True, False)`, or a `case ... when ... then` or maybe an bitwise and (the result is the same)

Comment: Hhmm, you're right...my pseudo SQL works at least in H2. I'm puzzled.

Comment: @MarcelStör I'll say tag one and include others in question.

Comment: That's valid ANSI SQL syntax.

Comment: Oracle have no boolean datatype, so there should not be a single code for all the DBMSes

Comment: [That is perfectly valid SQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=74243e30e999a8ae88faf707222ac200) - but Oracle does not support that.

Comment: Any null values involved?

Comment: @jarlh no, simplifies things

Comment: @MarcelStör which datatype(s) do you use for each boolean in each RDBMS? And are you required to use these (types)?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, use `case` might be a better option because Oracle is included, To the best of my knowledge Oracle can't have a boolean column so usually we just use a `varchar(1)` or `char(1)` with `t/f`

So instead of having `boolean` column, you can considerate just use string column with `t/f` across all database, then a simple `case` (like below) can work with all of them.

```
select case when colA = 't' and colB = 't' then 't' else 'f' end as joint_bool 
from [TableName]
```

Comment: IMHO the more logical representation of a boolean in Oracle is `NUMBER(1)` but your answer still applies of course.

Comment: surely number is  a good and better option, but my working environment (oracle) use sting so I am kinda get use to it.

Comment: Note, this will not work properly if null values are involved.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the feedback. My application uses Liquibase to abstract schema definitions. It maps the boolean type as follows:

- H2: BOOLEAN
- Postgres: BOOLEAN
- Oracle: NUMBER(1)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626825/131929

This is also the answer to @codeflush.dev's Q in the comments.

> which datatype(s) do you use for each boolean in each RDBMS?

Given the list of effective RDBMS types above one way to go about this surrogate boolean column in the result set is to use `BITAND`. It is supported in the all database products relevant to this questions.

The more general `CASE WHEN` approach presented in the other answer is likely ok if you can't use `BITAND`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
(case when boolean_col_A =1 and boolean_col_B=1 then 'true'
else 'false'
end  ) joint_bool 
from foo where id = 42
```

try this.

Comment: Effectively the same as T.Peter's earlier answer, no?